# golang influxdb client response to array or slice

Tags: go, influxdb

I have a go program to query an Influxdb via Influxdb client.

Function queryDB:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/tree/master/client#querying-data
is called via

```
resp, err := queryDB(c, "SELECT ip FROM events WHERE time >= '2016-10-24T00:00:00Z' AND time < '2016-10-24T01:00:00Z' ORDER BY time DESC")
```

when I do

```
fmt.Printf("%s", resp)
```

I get something like

```
[{[{events map[] [time ip] [[2016-10-24T00:12:12.123456Z 192.168.123.107] /*...and so on...*/ [2016-10-24T00:24:24.123456Z 192.168.123.103]]}] [] }]
```

How can I get a simple array or slice consisting of time and IP address?

Comment: can you put complete output here a small sample would be fine but need to be complete

Comment: sample output:`[{[{events map[] [time distinct] [[1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 192.168.123.100] [1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 192.168.123.233] [1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 192.168.123.24] [1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 192.168.123.222] [1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 192.168.123.112]]}] [] }]`

Comment: What's the structure of `resp`?

Comment: function queryDB returns ´res []client.Result

Comment: I think its this: ´type Response struct {
    Results []Result
    Err     error
}´ https://gowalker.org/github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client#Response wich has ´type Result struct {
    Series   []models.Row
    Messages []*Message
    Err      error
}´ https://gowalker.org/github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client#Result

Comment: @myNickname I'd recommend against using the InfluxDB client in the repo. There is currently an [experimental client](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client) that is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it:

```
var myData [][]interface{} = make([][]interface{}, len(resp[0].Series[0].Values))
            for i, d := range resp[0].Series[0].Values {
                myData[i] = d
            }

fmt.Println("", myData[0]) //first element in slice
fmt.Println("", myData[0][0])
fmt.Println("", myData[0][1])
```

output:

```
[2016-10-24T00:12:12.123456Z 192.168.123.107]
2016-10-24T00:12:12.123456Z
192.168.123.107
```